# JSP's variable's width

Tags: css, jsp, variables

I'm doing a project with JSP/Servlet
I have a variable, which value I collect in a JSP file. Then I want to render it inside a div, like so:

```
  <div>
      <p> <%=myVariable%> </p>
   </div>
```

I have set my div's width to 560px. This `myVariable` is supposed to contain some text info. But when the text is a little bit longer, it goes outside the div's border.
How do I make it so, that the text stays inside the div?
Thank you!

Comment: is it compulsory that ur width remain 560px?

Comment: yes, it has to be 560px, because it is nested in another div.

Comment: So what is the behaviour you want if the text is longer than 560px?

Comment: I want it to stay inside the div. If the text is longer than 560px, it should go to the next line and so on.

Comment: By default the `<p>` tag is a block level element, so it shouldn't overflow its parent. Unless of course you have a defined `height` set on the `<div>` ? Or you have a really really long word with no breaks in it (But I doubt that's the case?)

Comment: Please give us an actual, minimal HTML + CSS example where this fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default behaviour does what you want already: http://jsfiddle.net/6uxQ8/

The only thing I can imagine is that somehow your string is not broken because it has no whitespace in it. In that case you can use the [`word-wrap`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp) property.

Comment: ohh, indeed I was testing just by entering a long long string with no white spaces, but now I tryed out with whitespaces (as it should be) and it worked. Thank You!